# My emails goes into spam folder despite DKIM, PTR, SPF records

Tags: email, gmail, email-spam, dkim, spf

I have problems with sending email from my server. The problem is that when i send a letter to gmail.сom, yahoo.com it get into **spam folder**. I have tried many things. The following is a brief report on the characteristics of my letters.

yandex.ru, mail.ru, rambler.ru receive emails from my server without problems

My email server:
ip 94.242.7.157
host mail.da.am
listening only on localhost:25 (refuse other connections)

Spamhaus is ok http://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/94.242.7.157
*(i have deleted my ip from spamhaus PBL two weeks ago, it was old issue)*
46 more blacklists are ok http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a94.242.7.157&run=toolpage

**PTR** record seems to be ok
**DKIM** signature marked as 'pass' by google and yahoo
**SPF** signature marked as 'pass' by google and yahoo
**DMARC** signature marked as 'pass' by google and yahoo

Yahoo for unknow reasons marked my emails with **X-YahooFilteredBulk: 94.242.7.157**

Here is raw content of example letter to gmail. It is activation letter wich has been send to user just after his registration in on my site:

```
Delivered-To: a@da.am
Received: by 10.112.20.73 with SMTP id l9csp105062lbe;
        Wed, 17 Apr 2013 09:25:42 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.112.155.40 with SMTP id vt8mr3898247lbb.70.1366215942667;
        Wed, 17 Apr 2013 09:25:42 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <robot@bannerd.ru>
Received: from mail.da.am (mail.da.am. [94.242.7.157])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id o5si471161laj.179.2013.04.17.09.25.42;
        Wed, 17 Apr 2013 09:25:42 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of robot@bannerd.ru designates 94.242.7.157 as permitted sender) client-ip=94.242.7.157;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of robot@bannerd.ru designates 94.242.7.157 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=robot@bannerd.ru;
       dkim=pass header.i=@bannerd.ru;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=none) d=bannerd.ru
Received: by mail.da.am (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id 9E92D1E80373; Wed, 17 Apr 2013 20:25:41 +0400 (MSK)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=bannerd.ru;
    s=bannerd; t=1366215941;
    bh=ARMYABZee/pyG7UP+Jdc9zS/Nr4Dh7RDeIMT+hFEgGo=;
    h=To:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:Reply-To:From:Date;
    b=QhLO9vL0Y5w0ctl+v3S1atnlTa5Eq6PjJGG91Sb4TfMb5xCKB6UqoKQWnMeKlOcbk
     SMhlwSbD8CsSkvppFMpKygjPl1+xHkLWv8a9mzNtdDvtoGMZX++Hiy5rdiUItcoQDm
     aH/nWQg0RPNSSq3e3PdYbIbRk0ldgUA9yl9NavmQ=
To: a@da.am
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0J/QvtC00YLQstC10YDQtNC40YLQtSwg0L/QvtC20LDQu9GD0LnRgdGC0LAs?=
 =?UTF-8?B?INCw0LTRgNC10YEg0Y3Qu9C10LrRgtGA0L7QvdC90YvQuSDQv9C+0YfRgtGL?=
 =?UTF-8?B?INC00LvRjyDQstCw0YjQtdCz0L4g0LDQutC60LDRg9C90YLQsA==?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:support@bannerd.ru>
Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?0J/QvtC00LTQtdGA0LbQutCwIEJhbm5lcmQucnU=?= <support@bannerd.ru>
Return-Receipt-To: <robot@bannerd.ru>
From: =?UTF-8?B?0KDQvtCx0L7Rgi3Qv9C+0YfRgtCw0LvRjNC+0L0gQmFubmVyZC5ydQ==?= <robot@bannerd.ru>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Message-Id: <20130417162541.9E92D1E80373@mail.da.am>
Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2013 20:25:41 +0400 (MSK)
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```

Please, help me!

Comment: I'd probably put some text before the activation code explaining what it is. The fact that there's no human readable text in the body could be what's tripping up the spam filter. I don't know for certain though, as I've never done anything like this.

Comment: @Dr.Cyanide: The text is human-readable if you know Russian. :)

Comment: @duskwuff Chrome is just rendering it as a bunch of without spaces or anything to me. Maybe that's part of the problem. Here's just a portion of it: "0KPQstCw0LbQsNC10LzRi9C5INCy0LXQsdC80LDRgdGC0LXRgCwNCg0K0JLRiyDQstCy0LXQu9C4INCw0LTRgNC10YEg0Y3Qu9C10LrRgtGA0L7QvdC90L7QuSDQv9C+0YfRgtGLIGFAZGEuYW0g0LIg0LrQsNGH0LXRgdGC0LLQtSDQu9C+0LPQuNC90LAg0LTQu9GPINCS0LDRiNC10Lkg0YPRh9C10YLQvdC+0Lkg0LfQsNC/0LjRgdC4INCyINGB0LjRgdGC0LXQvNC1IEJhbm5lcmQuDQrQoSDRhtC10LvRjNGOINC30LDQstC10YDRiNC10L3QuNGPINC/0YDQvtGG0LXRgdGB0LAg0L3QsNC8INC90YPQttC90L4g0L/QvtC00YLQstC10YDQtNC40YLRjCwg0YfRgtC+INC00LDQvdC90YvQuSDQsNC"

Comment: It's base64 encoded. This is normal for Unicode text in emails.

Comment: Try removing it, if it passes the spam filters, you know it is what is tripping it. If that is the issue, you might have to go with html ascii characters instead (if Russian is even supported...).

Comment: Try https://postmaster.google.com/ to get some info, apart from pulling up DMARC reports which also can help you to see the light.